# Add links to post categories and taxonomies in wysiwyg link modal?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, visual-editor

I want to link to post categories and taxonomies in the text editor. With the "add link" modal I only can add links to existing posts, pages and custom post types but not to their categories and taxonomies.

I found nothing about this in the codex. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

I found the plugin ["Better Internal Link Search"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-internal-link-search/) and this does the job!

Comment: Nice find! Did the trick for me too.